# gradle processResources with different replacement and renaming rules

Tags: java, gradle

I'd love to filter specific java resources in my gradle project. Where some files should have replaced contents only, some should be also renamed (and have different content replaced).

My gradle java project setup is:

```
> cat build.gradle 
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java { 
            resources { 
                srcDirs = [ "foo" ]
                include '**/**'
            } 
        }       
    }
}

processResources {
    include '**/file_a.txt'
    filter { String line ->
        line
            .replace("foo", "fool" )
        }   
}


processResources {
    include '**/file_b.txt'
    rename { "file_c.txt" }
    filter { String line ->
        line
            .replace("ipsum", "zzz" )
        }   
}                                        

> cat foo/file_a.txt 
my name is foo
test ipsum 

> cat foo/file_b.txt
lorem ipsum ...
```

Once running:

> gradle build

I get:

```
> ls build/resources/main 
file_c.txt

> cat build/resources/main/file_c.txt
my name is fool
test zzz
```

However I'd like to get both files, where only `file_b.txt` would be renamed and both would be replaced by the specific rules. What is the proper way to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, found the solution myself, following seems to be working as expected:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java { 
            resources { 
                srcDirs = [ "foo" ]
                include '**/**'
                exclude '**/*.txt'
            } 
        }       
    }
}

processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from 'foo/file_a.txt'
        filter { String line ->
            line
                .replace("foo", "fool" )
            }   
    }

    with copySpec {
        from 'foo/file_b.txt'
        rename { "file_c.txt" }
        filter { String line ->
            line
                .replace("ipsum", "zzz" )
            }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, think that resources and filtered resources should be kept separate. Ie `src/main/resources` and `src/main/filteredResources`. I also thing you should avoid excludes (eg `exclude '**/*.txt'`) `resources` and `filteredResources` directories should contain ONLY what will end up in the jar... NOTHING ELSE

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from 'src/main/filteredResources'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [foo: 'fool', ipsum: 'zzz'])
    }
}
```

The above snippet will replace `@foo@` and `@ipsum@` in ALL files in the `src/main/filteredResources` folder

Comment: well, I see your point, but I'm in a situation, that I need to filter specific stuff in the specific files, moreover, I need to rename particular ones

Comment: Fair enough... I don't fully grok your use case. Why can't you name the templates exactly the same as the target files? Have you considered using a templating language such as [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) or [velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/)?