# How can I print the applications version early in the log in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to print my applications version early in the log before any of my other code has a chance to execute, so that if an error happens the version is included in the log file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main( String... args ) {
        var ctx = SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
        ctx.getBeanProvider( BuildProperties.class ).ifAvailable( bp -> {
            LogManager.getLogger( Application.class ).info( bp.getArtifact() );
        } );
    }
}
```

but the block in `ifAvailable` doesn't get executed, I'd like to print the version especially.

note: this is in `build.gradle.kts`

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo() // generates BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF/build-info.properties
}
```

*update* fails with no such bean...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main( String... args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner( BuildProperties bp ) {
        return args -> LogManager.getLogger( Application.class ).info( bp.getArtifact() );
    }
}
```

*update 2:* doesn't have to be after the banner, but has to be early enough that it prints before any validation/errors from custom code.

Comment: Did you check to see if the `build-info.properties` file is being generated in the right location (`META-INF/`) ?

Comment: @Rentius2407  `BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF/build-info.properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

presuming you're fatpacking a jar (otherwise some modifications are needed)

```
tasks.withType<BootJar>().configureEach {
    enabled = true
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "Implementation-Title" to project.description,
            "Implementation-Version" to project.version
        )
    }
}
```

then [customize your `banner.txt`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-banner); e.g.

```
${application.title} ${application.version}
```

Comment: What if I need other things from buildinfo? Say build.group or anything custom.

Answer (score 1):

You can your custom `banner.txt` with `spring.banner.location` property and use Gradle [resource filtering](https://dzone.com/articles/resource-filtering-gradle) with [`processResources` task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774449/gradle-processresources-with-different-replacement-and-renaming-rules) to replace placeholders in this file with the same properties that were used by `build-info`.

Comment: not a terrible idea, but it has a flaw of I'm not using maven... which is mentioned

Comment: @xenoterracide Gradle has `processResources` task, not sure how it aligns with `buildInfo`

Comment: you don't need to process  resources, after a couple of hours of work... see my answer :/

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains something of a round about technique,
but may be useful.

**Assumptions First:**

1. You are building an executable, fat Jar.
2. You are using the spring-boot-maven-plugin to build the jar.

**Answer:**

1. Configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin to include build information in the artifact.  See section [91.1 Generate Build Information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-build-info) (in the spring-boot reference) for instructions.
2. Be sure to enable the build info contributor.  This should be enabled by default (search the spring boot reference for "management.info.build.enabled" to find the property that enables his info contributor.
3. Get the list of `InfoContributor` beans from the application context.  I do this by autowiring a `List` in a component as follows:

   > @Autowired
   >   private List<InfoContributor> infoContributorList;
4. Run the list of InfoContributor objects (in your case there should only be one, the build info) and display the info.

Here is some code (poorly configured on my part)

> final Info info;
>      final Info.Builder infoBuilder = new Info.Builder();
>      final Map infoMap;
>
> for (final InfoContributor current : infoContributorList)
>      {
>        current.contribute(infoBuilder);
>      }
>
> info = infoBuilder.build();
>
> infoMap = info.getDetails();